# In tornado, are secure cookie secret?

Tags: security, cookies, tornado

When i use the secret cookie functions, to set and get the cookie, the http client get and send a string containing the cookie.

I know the cookie is secure : the client can't alter the content of the cookie without knowing the key.

But is the cookie secret ? Can the client extract the cookie from the string without the key ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookies are signed but not encrypted, so the client can easily see the data they contain (it's just base64-encoded).  If you need to keep the contents of the cookie secret you must encrypt it separately.

Comment: Any option for encrypting ?

Comment: Not currently; you'll need to use a separate library (I've used keyczar in the past and would recommend it)